# How can i set width and height for canvas image

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html5-canvas

I was using angular canvas painter and i want to set the image height as auto and width as 100% for canvas image but its only taking pixel value.

```
 options.width = options.width || '480';
   options.height = options.height || '350';
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Below is the Js fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/Raviteja123/vjy2w0e3/1/]

Comment: Why can't you use something like this? ng-style="{'width': "auto"'}" or else specify a class and write styles in the css.

Comment: We need to set width and height for canvas image i tried by setting in html and passed the values to directive file but its not worked.

Comment: Can you share few codes? with the given code,its difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl as canvasctrl">
<input type="file" name="img[]" class="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().ocular_file(this.files)" ngf-select ng-model="file" style="position:relative;width:auto;height:auto;">
<div pw-canvas            versionright="canvasctrl.versionright"  options="{undo: true,color: selectedColor, lineWidth: selectedLineWidth,imageSrc:thumbnail.dataUrl}"ng-show="showCanvasdiv" >
 <div class="pwCanvasPaint" style=""></div>
  </div>
  <div pw-color-selector="['#000', '#9CB199', '#CF3759', '#485247', '#E77547', '#D38E47', '#0A6A74', '#153974']" color="selectedColor">
      </div>
      
                      
<div class="undo">
   <button ng-click="canvasctrl.undo()"
   ng-disabled="canvasctrl.versionright < 1">Undo ({{canvasctrl.versionright}})</button></div>
  
                                      
</div>
</body>
<style>
.alpha{height:100%;width:100%;border:1px solid red;}
canvas{height:100%;width:100%;border:1px solid green;}

</style>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive('pwCanvas', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        options: '=',
        versionright: '='
      },
      //templateUrl: '../templates/canvas.html',
      link: function postLink(scope, elm) {

        var isTouch = !!('ontouchstart' in window);
        elm.addClass('alpha');
        var PAINT_START = isTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';
        var PAINT_MOVE = isTouch ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove';
        var PAINT_END = isTouch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

        //set default options
        var options = scope.options;
        options.canvasId = options.customCanvasId || 'pwCanvasMain';
        options.tmpCanvasId = options.customCanvasId ? (options.canvasId + 'Tmp') : 'pwCanvasTmp';
       options.backgroundColor = options.backgroundColor || '#fff';
        options.color = options.color || '#000';
        options.undoEnabled = options.undoEnabled || false;
        options.opacity = options.opacity || 0.9;
        options.lineWidth = options.lineWidth || 1;
        options.undo = options.undo || false;
        //alert(options.imageSrc);
        options.imageSrc = options.imageSrc || 'img/optha/image-workgd.png';
       
        // background image
        if (options.imageSrc) {

          var image = new Image();
          image.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
          };
          image.src = options.imageSrc;
          scope.$watch(function(){
           return options.imageSrc;
          },function(newVal){
           scope.options.imageSrc = newVal;
          });
           scope.$watch('options.imageSrc', function(newVal) {
           // alert(newVal);
             scope.options.imageSrc =  newVal;
             image.src = newVal;
           });

        }

        //undo
        if (options.undo) {
          var undoCache = [];
          scope.$watch(function() {
            return undoCache.length;
          }, function(newVal) {
            scope.versionright = newVal;
          });

          scope.$watch('versionright', function(newVal) {
            if (newVal < 0) {
              scope.versionright = 0;
              return;
            }
            if (newVal >= undoCache.length) {
              scope.versionright = undoCache.length;
              return;
            }
            undo(newVal);
          });
        }

        //create canvas and context
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id = options.canvasId;
        var canvasTmp = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvasTmp.id = options.tmpCanvasId;
        angular.element(canvasTmp).css({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        });
        elm.find('div').append(canvas);
        elm.find('div').append(canvasTmp);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var ctxTmp = canvasTmp.getContext('2d');

        //inti variables
        var point = {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        };
        var ppts = [];

        //set canvas size
        canvas.width = canvasTmp.width;
        canvas.height = canvasTmp.height;

        //set context style
        ctx.fillStyle = options.backgroundColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctxTmp.globalAlpha = options.opacity;
        ctxTmp.lineJoin = ctxTmp.lineCap = 'round';
        ctxTmp.lineWidth = 10;
        ctxTmp.strokeStyle = options.color;


        //Watch options
        
        scope.$watch('options.lineWidth', function(newValue) {
          if (typeof newValue === 'string') {
            newValue = parseInt(newValue, 10);
          }
          if (newValue && typeof newValue === 'number') {
            ctxTmp.lineWidth = options.lineWidth = newValue;
          }
        });

        scope.$watch('options.color', function(newValue) {
          if (newValue) {
            //ctx.fillStyle = newValue;
            ctxTmp.strokeStyle = ctxTmp.fillStyle = newValue;
          }
        });

        scope.$watch('options.opacity', function(newValue) {
          if (newValue) {
            ctxTmp.globalAlpha = newValue;
          }
        });

        var getOffset = function(elem) {
          var bbox = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
          return {
            left: bbox.left,
            top: bbox.top
          };
        };

        var setPointFromEvent = function(point, e) {
          if (isTouch) {
            point.x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - getOffset(e.target).left;
            point.y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - getOffset(e.target).top;
          } else {
            point.x = e.offsetX !== undefined ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
            point.y = e.offsetY !== undefined ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;
          }
        };


        var paint = function(e) {
          if (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setPointFromEvent(point, e);
          }

          // Saving all the points in an array
          ppts.push({
            x: point.x,
            y: point.y
          });

          if (ppts.length === 3) {
            var b = ppts[0];
            ctxTmp.beginPath();
            ctxTmp.arc(b.x, b.y, ctxTmp.lineWidth / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, !0);
            ctxTmp.fill();
            ctxTmp.closePath();
            return;
          }

          // Tmp canvas is always cleared up before drawing.
          ctxTmp.clearRect(0, 0, canvasTmp.width, canvasTmp.height);

          ctxTmp.beginPath();
          ctxTmp.moveTo(ppts[0].x, ppts[0].y);

          for (var i = 1; i < ppts.length - 2; i++) {
            var c = (ppts[i].x + ppts[i + 1].x) / 2;
            var d = (ppts[i].y + ppts[i + 1].y) / 2;
            ctxTmp.quadraticCurveTo(ppts[i].x, ppts[i].y, c, d);
          }

          // For the last 2 points
          ctxTmp.quadraticCurveTo(
            ppts[i].x,
            ppts[i].y,
            ppts[i + 1].x,
            ppts[i + 1].y
          );
          ctxTmp.stroke();
        };

        var copyTmpImage = function() {
          if (options.undo) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              undoCache.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasTmp.width, canvasTmp.height));
              if (angular.isNumber(options.undo) && options.undo > 0) {
                undoCache = undoCache.slice(-1 * options.undo);
              }
            });
          }
          canvasTmp.removeEventListener(PAINT_MOVE, paint, false);
          ctx.drawImage(canvasTmp, 0, 0);
          ctxTmp.clearRect(0, 0, canvasTmp.width, canvasTmp.height);
          ppts = [];
        };

        var startTmpImage = function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          canvasTmp.addEventListener(PAINT_MOVE, paint, false);

          setPointFromEvent(point, e);
          ppts.push({
            x: point.x,
            y: point.y
          });
          ppts.push({
            x: point.x,
            y: point.y
          });

          paint();
        };

        var initListeners = function() {
          canvasTmp.addEventListener(PAINT_START, startTmpImage, false);
          canvasTmp.addEventListener(PAINT_END, copyTmpImage, false);

          if (!isTouch) {
            var MOUSE_DOWN;

            document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
            document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);

            scope.$on('$destroy', removeEventListeners);

            canvasTmp.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseenter);
            canvasTmp.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseleave);
          }

          function mousedown() {
            MOUSE_DOWN = true;
          }

          function mouseup() {
            MOUSE_DOWN = false;
          }

          function removeEventListeners() {
            document.body.removeEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
            document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
          }

          function mouseenter(e) {
            // If the mouse is down when it enters the canvas, start a path
            if (MOUSE_DOWN) {
              startTmpImage(e);
            }
          }

          function mouseleave(e) {
            // If the mouse is down when it leaves the canvas, end the path
            if (MOUSE_DOWN) {
              copyTmpImage(e);
            }
          }
        };

        var undo = function(versionright) {
         console.log(undoCache.length);
          if (undoCache.length > 0) {
            ctx.putImageData(undoCache[versionright], 0, 0);
            undoCache = undoCache.slice(0, versionright);
          }
        };

        initListeners();
      }
    };
  });

app.controller("myctrl", function($scope,$timeout) {
 $scope.thumbnail = [];
    $scope.showCanvasdiv = false;
    // Read the image using the filereader 
    $scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null;
   $scope.ocular_file = function(files){
    if (files != null) {
        var file = files[0];
        if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
          $timeout(function() {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file); // convert the image to data url. 
            fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                $scope.showCanvasdiv = true;
              
              $timeout(function() {
               
                $scope.thumbnail.dataUrl = e.target.result; // Retrieve the image. 
                //console.log($scope.thumbnail.dataUrl);
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    };
    this.undo = function(){
       
          this.versionright--;
    };
});
</script>
```

I tired to use auto and it works fine, using a directive. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Nandagopal have you used angular canvas painter plugin ?

Comment: Nope,Can you share your codes? Wil try to work on that.

Comment: Sure i will arrange a fiddle for that.

Comment: @Nandagopal you can find the JS fiddle here [Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Raviteja123/vjy2w0e3/1/)

Comment: @Nandagopal Have you found the JS fiddle ?

Comment: Can you post here the link which you clicked

Comment: I'm able to open it now. I directly clicked on the link so it had ] in the end that's why.I'll look into the codes.Thanks.Hey can you send me the steps?

Comment: First we preview the image which is select from the file input and the assign it into background to the canvas from directive file we need to set the image height as 'auto' and width as 100% to fit the image to that canvas but its not taking those values

Comment: So,I browsed the image and how do we preview it? I have already changed the values to px.

Comment: You can set the values to `options.width = options.width || '480';
   options.height = options.height || '350';` like this then you can preview the image

Comment: Yea,Able to see preview it.Will check.

Comment: Previously i tried with window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight but its not working

Comment: Did you check my fiddle?

Comment: Cool :) I'll update the answer then.Please accept and upvote it.

Comment: Please let me know once you updated the answer or JSfiddle

Comment: I've updated the codes,The problem is if we give auto or 100% then the image is affecting.I'll work on it.Let me know if there are any other issues.